# $.ajax works only when put alert()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried to load content inside content those are loaded previously with AJAX. I put the code

**with load():**

```
jQuery("#contentpage").on("submit", "#loginform", my = function() {
    $("#contentpage").load("/logincheck.jsp");
    alert("this is required ");
});
```

**with $.ajax():**

```
jQuery("#contentpage").on("submit", "#loginform", function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/logincheck.jsp',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#contentpage').html(data);
        }
    });

    alert("this is required ");
});
```

`#loginform` is a HTML form loaded with previous AJAX request, I successfully access in with `.on()` function.

But the problem is when I submit `#loginform` *without* putting `alert('this is required')` box then its refreshing the whole page. 
Also content inside `#contentpage` are also not changing.

But if I do the same with putting `alert("this is required")`, its working fine, contents are getting loaded in `#contentpage` without refreshing whole page.

Is this a timing issue? Ajax request takes time and it's asynchronous? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Why do you mix `jQuery` and `$`? You can make your code nicer by using only `$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
        jQuery("#contentpage").on("submit","#loginform",my=function(event){ 
             event.preventDefault();
             $("#contentpage").load("/logincheck.jsp");
             alert("this is required ");
        });
```

This should at least stop the page from refreshing and may sort out the other problems as well.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

async key is default `true` and should change it to `false`

```
$.ajax({
    async:false,
    url: '/logincheck.jsp',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#contentpage').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: async key is Default: true and should change it to false