# Django: AJAX query returns intersection of the current and previous ResultSet

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Okay, so I'm trying to display relevant search results in a HTML datalist tag as a user enters text into a HTML text input. To achieve this, I have the following HTML/JS:

```
<input class="search-input" autocomplete="off" id="txtSearch" list="suggestions" onkeyup="searchOpen()" value="{{ query }}" type="text" name="query">
<datalist id="suggestions"></datalist>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery.curCSS = function(element, prop, val) {
        return jQuery(element).css(prop, val);
    };

    function searchOpen() {
        var search = $('#txtSearch').val()
        var data = { search: search };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/search_suggestions/',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            minLength: 3,
            jsonpCallback: 'searchResult'
        });
    }

    function searchResult(data) {

        var dataList = document.getElementById('suggestions');

        data.forEach(function(item) {
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = item;
            dataList.appendChild(option);
        });
    };
</script>
```

Sending an AJAX request to this Class Based View in Django:

```
class SearchSuggestions(View):

    def get(self, request):

        search_term = self.request.GET['search']
        query_set = Names.objects.filter(name__istartswith=search_term)[:5]
        results = []

        for r in query_set:
            results.append(r.name)

        results = json.dumps(results)
        # print(results)
        resp = self.request.GET['callback'] + '(' + results + ');'

        return HttpResponse(resp, content_type='application/json')
```

Say I have a database table with the following entries:

{ 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af' }

If I type a letter, for example 'a'. I get the first 5 results that start with 'a':

{ 'aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae' }

which is the expected behavior. However, when I type the second letter, it is further slicing the initially returned QuerySet, rather than making a new Query. So 'ae' returns one result, but 'af' returns no results. How can I make a new db query every time the user enters text?

Comment: So, it's getting buggy here: `query_set = Names.objects.filter(name__istartswith=search_term)[:5]`

Comment: Correct, that's where I make the query, and slice it. But it's my first time with AJAX, so I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong on the front end to make it bug out at that line.

Comment: And if you replace that line with `query_set = Names.objects.all().filter(name__istartswith=search_term)[:5]`
`

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing. I have `.all()` included in my actual code. I removed it to make that line a little shorter when posting to SO. I'll try it again though, with and without `.all()` to make sure.

Comment: A second check, in your javascript `searchOpen` function, put an `alert(search)` just to make sure that it's looking for the right term....

Comment: Probably you can verify by hitting url from browser ajax/search_suggestions/?search=af....

Comment: That should works too...Because I can't see anything wrong with your python-django code

Comment: Yeah, I can see the urls popping up in my terminal, since it's a Django app. But I tried the alert thing anyway, and put it just above" `$.ajax({` and the weirdest thing happened. It started working, I think perfectly, though it's hard to tell, without testing a bit more. I removed the alert, and it broke again, put it back again and it fixed it. So I think I maybe have some small syntax error in my JS.

Comment: me too had come across this type of issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332163/ajax-works-only-when-put-alert, Not sure it is related .. good if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @NikhilRupanawar, I'll take a look at that. And going on from my previous comment, the line `var search = $('#txtSearch').val()` was missing a semi colon, but no change in behavior after adding it.

Comment: Maybe you are using the `keydown` event...try changing it to the `keyup` event

Answer (score 0):

I suspect an AJAX timing issue. $.ajax() can take a little while to run. You are trying to build the data outside the AJAX call and it may be that when you get to the next call the previous one is still running, or something like that. The alert() would effectively force things to slow down. Try:

```
function searchOpen() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/search_suggestions/',
        data: { search: $('#txtSearch').val(); },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        minLength: 3,
        jsonpCallback: 'searchResult'
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think you might be onto something. There was a slight change, but still not quite right. Now, it works as I keep typing, but if I delete the text and try a different search (rather than hitting submit), it behaves as before; searching for the second query string in the QuerySet from the first.

Comment: Instead of an alert() use a console.log(). That will not have the same level of delay as an alert() but will let you see what is being sent. The other thing is to look at the Network log. All of this is easy in Firefox or Chrome Web Developer Extensions (or something like that - name varies between browsers).

Comment: Hmm. `console.log(search)` is printing the correct query. The network tab seems to be showing everything as expected (I'm getting responses in around 200~300ms). There's a lot of info though, so I'm still looking through it all.

Comment: Actually, scrap that. The response in the network tab contains the correct results. But they are different from the results being displayed, leading me to believe it's a problem with my HTML (or how my datalist is being populated). I'll edit my question to include my HTML, but thanks to your suggestions, I feel confident I can find the problem. If I manage to fix it, I'll post the solution I come up with.